# TypeError: Cannot read propery length in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

in this application i am using reactjs for frontend node js for backed....
i am facing problem when i try to return the length of array in react. the error is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'.

Cart.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import { API } from "../backend";
import Base from "./Base";
import Card from "./Card";
import { loadCart } from "./helper/cartHelper";
import Paymentb from "./Paymentb";

const Cart = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(loadCart());
  }, [reload]);

  const loadAllProducts = products => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>This section is to load products</h2>
        {products.map((product, index) => (
          <Card
            key={index}
            product={product}
            removeFromCart={true}
            addtoCart={false}
            setReload={setReload}
            reload={reload}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
  const loadCheckout = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>This section for checkout</h2>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Base title="Cart Page" description="Ready to checkout">
      <div className="row text-center">
        <div className="col-6">
          {products.length > 0 ? (
            loadAllProducts(products)
          ) : (
            <h4>No products</h4>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
          <Paymentb products={products} setReload={setReload} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Base>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Paymentb.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { loadCart, cartEmpty } from "./helper/cartHelper";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getmeToken, processPayment } from "./helper/paymentbHelper";
import { createOrder } from "./helper/orderHelper";
import { isAuthenticated } from "../auth/helper";

import DropIn from "braintree-web-drop-in-react";

const Paymentb = ({ products, setReload = f => f, reload = undefined }) => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    loading: false,
    success: false,
    clientToken: null,
    error: "",
    instance: {}
  });

  const userId = isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().user._id;
  const token = isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().token;

  const getToken = (userId, token) => {
    getmeToken(userId, token).then(info => {
      // console.log("INFORMATION", info);
      if (info.error) {
        setInfo({ ...info, error: info.error });
      } else {
        const clientToken = info.clientToken;
        setInfo({ clientToken });
      }
    });
  };

  const showbtdropIn = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {info.clientToken !== null && products.length > 0 ? (
          <div>
            <DropIn
              options={{ authorization: info.clientToken }}
              onInstance={instance => (info.instance = instance)}
            />
            <button className="btn btn-block btn-success" onClick={onPurchase}>
              Buy
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h3>Please login or add something to cart</h3>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getToken(userId, token);
  }, []);

  const onPurchase = () => {
    setInfo({ loading: true });
    let nonce;
    let getNonce = info.instance.requestPaymentMethod().then(data => {
      nonce = data.nonce;
      const paymentData = {
        paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
        amount: getAmount()
      };
      processPayment(userId, token, paymentData)
        .then(response => {
          setInfo({ ...info, success: response.success, loading: false });
          console.log("PAYMENT SUCCESS");
          const orderData = {
            products: products,
            transaction_id: response.transaction.id,
            amount: response.transaction.amount
          };
          createOrder(userId, token, orderData);
          cartEmpty(() => {
            console.log("Did we got a crash?");
          });

          setReload(!reload);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setInfo({ loading: false, success: false });
          console.log("PAYMENT FAILED");
        });
    });
  };

  const getAmount = () => {
    let amount = 0;
    products.map(p => {
      amount = amount + p.price;
    });
    return amount;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Your bill is {getAmount()} $</h3>
      {showbtdropIn()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Paymentb;
```

CartHelper.js

```
export const addItemToCart = (item, next) => {
  let cart = [];
  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    }
    cart.push({
      ...item,
      count: 1
    });
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    next();
  }
};

export const loadCart = () => {
  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    }
  }
};

export const removeItemFromCart = productId => {
  let cart = [];
  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    }
    cart.map((product, i) => {
      if (product._id === productId) {
        cart.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
  }
  return cart;
};

export const cartEmpty = next => {
  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    localStorage.removeItem("cart");
    let cart = [];
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    next();
  }
};[here is my error code][1]
```

[1]: [in this link shows the error][1]

https://ibb.co/HCWKhxp

don't know what to do?

Comment: After this `const [products, setProducts] = useState([])` try to print `products` & check. Also you might need to add null check like : `products && products.length > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

When no `cart` items present in the localStorage, your `loadCart` function returns undefined automatically. Return an empty array instead.

**CartHelper.js**

```js
...
export const loadCart = () => {
  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    }
  }
  return [] //<---------- like this
};
...
```